# How to reduce IO wait when serving large static files on NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I am wondering how to setup NGINX to server large (1-4 GB) static files without killing disk I/O wait caused by simultaneous reading.
How do file-servers achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me **readahead** changed everything. wa (iowait) went from 30% to 0.
Load Average from 4.00 to 0.04
Only by increasing it from 256 to 4096 with this command:

```
blockdev --setra 4096 /dev/sda3
```

Success Story: https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=35113

Tutorial: http://fibrevillage.com/storage/291-blockdev-command-examples

Answer (score 2):

These are would help you to reduce I/O on Disk:

1. Turn on `sendfile`in NGINX.
2. Use VFS File System for your partition.
3. Adjust `output_buffers` in NGINX.
4. Disable `directio` in NGINX.

Comment: Thanks! Are these still valid if NGINX is used as reverse proxy or not? Because i did not consider that, i might need to remove Apache altogether first.

Comment: These are important when you use NGINX as a standalone web server or reverse proxy. For reversed proxied NGINX you must adjust some variables for proxy_*. such as proxy_buffering, proxy_buffer_size, etc..

Comment: Do you have enough RAM for disk caching? If you're serving many large files simultaneously including many people downloading the same file you might benefit from having the OS cache them in RAM. You could also use a CDN, or distribute them via S3, which makes it someone else's problem.

Answer (score 1):

iowait is not necessarily bad, as long as you are getting the expected performance (response time, throughput) out of the system. It can be reduced:

- More RAM for a better hit ratio on file system cache.
- Faster storage system.

On Linux, consider [threaded async I/O](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#aio) for large requests, and buffered I/O for smaller ones. AIO is not for everyone as it will hit the storage with many parallel requests and no file system buffer. But it can let worker jobs continue while the I/Os are still in progress.

```
sendfile       on;
aio            threads;
directio       8m;
```